# packetsocket opened on loopback device receives all the packets twice. How to filter these duplicate entries?

Tags: sockets, tcpdump

when i open a `packetsocket` on a loopback interface (lo) and listen all the packets are seen twice. why is it so?

But a capture on the interface using tcpdump correctly ignores the duplicate entries.  see the 'packets received by filter' (which contains the duplicate packets) and 'packets captured'. How is this filtering done

tcpdump -i lo -s 0

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
11:00:08.439542 IP 12.0.0.3 > localhost.localdomain: icmp 64: echo request seq 1
11:00:08.439559 IP localhost.localdomain > 12.0.0.3: icmp 64: echo reply seq 1
11:00:09.439866 IP 12.0.0.3 > localhost.localdomain: icmp 64: echo request seq 2
11:00:09.439884 IP localhost.localdomain > 12.0.0.3: icmp 64: echo reply seq 2
11:00:10.439389 IP 12.0.0.3 > localhost.localdomain: icmp 64: echo request seq 3
11:00:10.439410 IP localhost.localdomain > 12.0.0.3: icmp 64: echo reply seq 3

6 packets captured
12 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

My code:

```
int main()
{
  int sockFd;

  if ( (sockFd=socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))<0 ) {
    perror("socket()");
    return -1;
  }

  /* bind the packet socket */
  struct sockaddr_ll addr;
  struct ifreq ifr;
  strncpy (ifr.ifr_name, "lo", sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));
  if(ioctl(sockFd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) == -1)
  {
    perror("iotcl");
    return -1;
  }
  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sll_family=AF_PACKET;
  addr.sll_protocol=htons(ETH_P_ALL);
  addr.sll_ifindex=ifr.ifr_ifindex;
  if ( bind(sockFd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) ) {
    perror("bind()");
    return -1;
  }

  char buffer[MAX_BUFFER+1];
  int tmpVal = 1;

  while(tmpVal > 0)
  {
    tmpVal = recv (sockFd, buffer, MAX_BUFFER, 0);
    cout<<"Received Pkt with Bytes "<<tmpVal <<endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Figured out the problem.

from libcaps code:

```
 *   - The loopback device gives every packet twice; on 2.2[.x] kernels,
 *     if we use PF_PACKET, we can filter out the transmitted version
 *     of the packet by using data in the "sockaddr_ll" returned by
 *     "recvfrom()", but, on 2.0[.x] kernels, we have to use
 *     PF_INET/SOCK_PACKET, which means "recvfrom()" supplies a
 *     "sockaddr_pkt" which doesn't give us enough information to let
 *     us do that.
```

the listening entity needs to filter the duplicate packet using the if_index got from recvfrom api.